# Stretched Image With Correct Constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, aspect-ratio

I've recently started a **tug-of-war** style game but in a single view application. I have a circular image over a `resetScore` button and all is well until I try to run the application. When I do so the image is out of the perfect circle form and stretched to a vertical oval. I have centered my image  in the `UIViewController` but that has not worked. With one of the reset variations, I set the `aspect ratio` of the image to that of the background and then I set the image to the aspect of 1-1 and the image came out in the right proportions on the simulator but then I tried that with one of the other reset variations an it did not work like it had before. If anyone knew of a solution towards this that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: what are the constraints

Comment: if it's an image, why not set make the mode of the image: Sale to Fill or Aspect Fit?